# Django's {{ csrf_token }} is outputting the token value only, without the hidden input markup

Tags: django, django-csrf

**Why isn't the markup for the hidden input field showing up when i use `{{ csrf_token }}`?**

Here's a snippet from my template:

```
<form action="." method="post">
{{ csrf_token }}
```

I'm expecting something like this to be generated:

```
<form action="." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="0c90dab91e22382cbaa5ef375f709167">
```

But instead, this is the HTML that's generated:

```
<form action="." method="post">
0c90dab91e22382cbaa5ef375f709167
```

I've done this many times and it's working fine in my other projects, but I don't know what I missed this time.

My views.py file looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html',
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see, I'm using RequestContext.  My middleware classes are defined like this in the settings.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

So I am using django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware.  Also, I'm on Django 1.3.0.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: Isn't it '{% csrf_token %}' - as a template tag, instead of outputting 'unicode(csrf_token)' ?

Comment: Gosh darn it.  I can't think or read straight at 2 in the morning.  You're absolutely right.  Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks much ;)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to use it as tag `{% csrf_token %}` not as a variable passed by your view `{{csrf_token}}`

Answer (score 11):

I use the next in my templates to solve your problem:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token }}' />
```